# NSString that contain lots of null termination?

Tags: iphone, encryption, nsstring, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In ios 3des encryption contain lots of null termination.when i convert NSData to NSString , it will endup to first null termination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717571/in-ios-3des-encryption-contain-lots-of-null-termination-when-i-convert-nsdata-to)

when i convert encrypted NSData to NSString because the data contain lots of null termination,NSString end up on first null termination, the variable is not able to contain the whole data. but i have to send encrypted string on the server. what can i do to convert NSData to NSString. string that contain all data means(if the data contain null termination. the string will not end up in that case)?

Comment: show code what you have got so far.

Comment: what type of encryption does server using? show me some sample?

Comment: Please edit your older question if required, don't ask a new, nearly identical one.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the conversion format like the following

```
NSString* myString;
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: sir, i have try this conversion format. but it will end up on first \0